# Removing the first item in a list using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I have a simple for loop that assigns a list to a variable, also I would like to delete the first element in the list for all the variables. The following code works well but it is not removing the first element on the lists, any suggestions?

```
    for x in range(0, len(dataList)-1):
        globals()['Row%s' % x] = dataList[x].split(',')
        del ['Row%s' % x] [0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following code works well but it is not removing the first element on the lists, any suggestions?

Because you're not telling it to remove the first element on the list. You're missing `globals()` in the delete line, and just creating a single element list `['Row1']` and deleting the `'Row1'`. Try:

```
 for x in range(0, len(dataList)-1):
    globals()['Row%s' % x] = dataList[x].split(',')
    del globals()['Row%s' % x] [0]
```

globals is a pretty grim hack for it though, instead use a dictionary or a normal list:

```
data = []
for x in range(0, len(datalist)-1):
    parts = x.split(',')
    del parts[0]
    data.append(parts)
```

Actually, Python can slice lists, and iterate over items without counting:

```
data = []
for x in datalist:
    parts = x.split(',')
    data.append(parts[1:])
```

Actually, it has a nice shortcut for building lists directly:

```
data = [x.split(',')[1:] for x in datalist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 for x in range(0, len(dataList)-1):
    if x == 0:
        continue
    globals()['Row%s' % x] = dataList[x].split(',')
    del ['Row%s' % x] [0]
```

Comment: What's `del ['Row%s' % x] [0]` going to do when it becomes `del ['Row5'][0]` ? Build a one item list with the string 'Row5', delete 'Row5', then throw the empty list away.